# Java & Android: Best way to create a dynamically expandable list of EditTexts in an activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

as I'm very new to Java and Android programming, I'm slowly getting used to the Android studio and the resource system, xml management and so on..

I'm trying to create an activity with a start count of 10 EditTextes, vertically listed in a LinearLayout.
Till this point, I can manage everything with a XML file & hard-coding the 10 EditTextes.

The problem with it is, that I'd like to provide a button that can be clicked by the user to automatically expand the list, for example add 10 more EditTextes to the list while runtime.
AFAIK, I can't solve this problem with XML only.
I know, I can get the layout (XML layout) to an object in my MainActivity class using LayoutInflater().inflate...

Here's my question:
Is it the right way to define the layout in a XML file and modify it with the method described above or would it be better to create the whole layout with Java in my class:
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    // add EditTexts
    // set attributes
    //setContentView(layout);

Are there any disadvantages using this way or is it the same as doing it with XML ? I mean, to address the created EditTexts later again, I also do have to pass an ID to them, so I also have to create an ids.xml where all those IDs are listed. That sounds like much work for me..

Am I on the right way or are there better options to create/manipulate layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill a listview with multiple views, it'll be best to use an Adapter. An Adapter can be used to fill a list, and add rows to this list. 
If you want a tutorial on how to create a list: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

The best part about an Adapter is, that you are able to create a custom layouts for it. So if you want to have an List Item with only EditTexts or ImageViews, it's easy to create. 
In the end, you'll only have 1 layout file for the row and 1 layout file which will contain the list.
Inflating a layout is always easier than to create them like " LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); // add EditTexts // set attributes //setContentView(layout);"
There are a lot of tutorials on how to create an Adapter, you'll get it!

Comment: Hi Hespen, thank you really much for that hint. I read a bit about that stuff and it sounds exactly like what I'm looking for! Btw.: using this method also uses an inflator, so I think (like you already mentioned) inflators are the classic way to programmatically access & manipulate xml, right?

Comment: Inflating is not really manipulating XML, it is just rendering the XML, after which you can access and change the rendered objects.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that was more or less what I meant :-P Ok so now I've got something to work with, thank's again